# XRDP - I can't access to my Ubuntu computer from Windows 10 Remote Desktop client

Tags: windows, remote, xrdp

I'm trying to access to my Ubuntu computer on local from Windows 10. So I installed xrdp:

```
sudo apt install xrdp
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
```

If I check the status of xrdp I can see it is active:

```
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-03-06 14:07:32 CET; 4min 48s ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
 Main PID: 9710 (xrdp)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2326)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
           └─9710 /usr/sbin/xrdp

mar 06 14:07:31 domar-ThinkCentre-M70e systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
mar 06 14:07:31 domar-ThinkCentre-M70e xrdp[9709]: (9709)(140614989543232)[DEBUG] Testing if xrdp can listen on 0.0.0.0 port 3389.
mar 06 14:07:31 domar-ThinkCentre-M70e xrdp[9709]: (9709)(140614989543232)[DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
mar 06 14:07:31 domar-ThinkCentre-M70e systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directo
mar 06 14:07:32 domar-ThinkCentre-M70e systemd[1]: Started xrdp daemon.
mar 06 14:07:33 domar-ThinkCentre-M70e xrdp[9710]: (9710)(140614989543232)[INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 9710
mar 06 14:07:33 domar-ThinkCentre-M70e xrdp[9710]: (9710)(140614989543232)[INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

But when I try to connect on remote desktop from Windows 10 I get the following error (it is on Spanish but is the typical error we get when we can't access to the other computer).

Important! I'm trying to connect with local IP address of my Ubuntu computer (192.168.1.203) and both computers are on the same network.

If I type:

```
netstat -an | grep ":3389"
```

That's what I get:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I tried with a lot of tutorials on the web (and on Youtube too) but I couldn't get a solution.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mw47.png)

[image: screenshot of message box showing error message]

Comment: Can anyone help me? :(

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm having an issue whereby xrdp says that it's running, but when I netstat, I see that nothing is listening on 3389.